# MySQL добавить записи сразу в 2 таблицы, при чём во вторую только ID которая auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста.. есть 2 таблицы:
Player и Accounts
В Player есть id - AUTO INCREMENT и в  Accounts есть ac_id тоже AUTO INCREMENT.

Как при добавлении данных в Player, прибавлять в Accounts +1 к ac_id?

Вот таким кодом добавляю в Player:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO player (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
```

Знаю что в запрос нужно добавить таблицу Accounts, и в её колонку вписать +1. Но не знаю как это сделать. С синтаксисом у меня неважно. Помогите пожалуйста.

Или может быть есть какие то другие, более правильные, методы взаимодействия между двух таблиц?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я спрашиваю как придобавлении нового пользователя в таблицу, прибавлять +1 к id в другой таблице

Comment: Что-то у вас с архитектурой явно не то. Ответьте на вопрос **зачем** вы это хотите делать?

Comment: Ну и структуру связи таблиц хорошо бы в вопросе описать

Comment: Я решил разделить таблицу авторизации accounts и таблицу (player) с прочими данными игроков, такими как имя, уровень и т д.
В таблице accounts  только id email и пароль, а вот связать как то эти таблицы я не могу.
Задача что бы при регистрации, юзер записывался в accounts давая только email и пароль, а в таблицу player, когда он жмякает кнопку submit, добавлялся ТОЛЬКО id, всё остальное заполняется позже в профиле. 
Почему решил разделить... не знаю. Для обучения. Я самообучаюсь. Задача для меня сложная.

Comment: "Ну и структуру связи таблиц хорошо бы в вопросе описать" - вот тут не понял. Я не связывал таблицы. Мне phpmyadmin ошибки выдает при попытке связать.

Comment: *как при добавлении нового пользователя в таблицу, прибавлять +1 к id в другой таблице* Триггером. *вот тут не понял.* Выполни `SHOW CREATE TABLE имя_таблицы;` для обеих таблиц и выложи результат. *Я не связывал таблицы.* Плохо. *Мне phpmyadmin ошибки выдает при попытке связать.* А более вменяемого средства управления нет? оптимум - прямой доступ через штатный клиент командной строки...

Comment: Триггером? Я читал о них, но не могу понять как этим триггером добавить... вернее не знаю как php запрос составить, с синтаксисом php у меня проблемы. Я в первом посте написал как я делаю запрос к БД. Куда там вставлять триггеры ума не приложу.

Там таблицы состоят из 3 полей.  Player (id, email, password) и вторая accounts вообще из 2... accounts (ac_id, name). 
Id из player и ac_id из accounts - PRIMARY KEY и AI
Чем phpmyadmin не вменяем? Мне он кажется удобным. Привык к нему.

Answer (score 0):

Так если `в Accounts ac_id тоже AUTO INCREMENT`, то точно таким же кодом как в вопросе добавляй любое значение в любое поле таблицы Accounts, то есть тупо добавить одну строку в таблицу и AUTO INCREMENT сам увеличит ac_id  на единицу. Только смысл таких движений вообще неясен.

Comment: mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO player (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO accounts (ac_id) VALUES -Не знаю какое значение тут прописать");
Пробовал:
VALUES ('+1')");
VALUES ('ac_id' +1)");
VALUES (ac_id+1)");
VALUES ac_id +1");
И т д.... ни одно не сработало

Comment: там что, таблица из одного столбца? добавь ещё любой и уже туда пиши что попало, лишь бы строка добавилась

Comment: К сожалению, пробовал так и не добавляется. Видимо 2 mysqli_query подряд... не хочет хавать

Comment: код полностью покажи. меня терзают смутные сомненья

Comment: переписываю его в ООП. Забил.